# Sources supporting sabbatical in the US for foreign mathematicians

Tags: mathematics, united-states, sabbatical

I would be interested to spend my sabbatical year at one of the US math departments.
I am a tenured mathematician affiliated with a non US university. I do not have a US citizenship.

**What are the sources available, e.g. grants, I could apply for in such a situation from which I could pay for my apartment in the US during the sabbatical?**

As far as I know in my country there are no such grants.